# Generate Index using CUDA-C

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia

I am trying to generate set of indices below:

I have a cuda block that consists of 20 blocks(blockIdx:from 0 -19) with each block subdivided into 4 blocks (sub block Idx: 0,1,2 and 3).

I am trying to generate index pattern like this :

threadIdx (tid),SubBlockIdxA(SA),SubBlockIdxB(SB), BlockIdxA(BA),BlockIdxB(BB)

```
            Required                           Obtained         
   tid  SBA SBB BA  BB    SBA  SBB BA  BB
    0   0   1   0   0       0   1   0   0
    1   1   0   0   1       1   0   0   1
    2   0   1   1   1       0   1   1   1
    3   1   0   1   2       1   0   1   2
    4   0   1   2   2       0   1   2   2
    5   1   0   2   3       1   0   2   3
    6   0   1   3   3       0   1   3   3
    7   1   0   3   4       1   0   3   4
    8   2   3   0   0       2   3   0   0
    9   3   2   0   1       3   2   0   1
    10  2   3   1   1       2   3   1   1
    11  3   2   1   2       3   2   1   2
    12  2   3   2   2       2   3   2   2
    13  3   2   2   3       3   2   2   3
    14  2   3   3   3       2   3   3   3
    15  3   2   3   4       3   2   3   4
    16  0   1   5   5       0   1   5   5
    17  1   0   5   6       1   0   5   6
    18  0   1   6   6       0   1   6   6
    19  1   0   6   7       1   0   6   7
    20  0   1   7   7       0   1   7   7
    21  1   0   7   8       1   0   7   8
    22  0   1   8   8       0   1   8   8
    23  1   0   8   9       1   0   8   9
    24  0   1   10  10      2   3   5   5
    25  1   0   10  11      3   2   5   6
    26  0   1   11  11      2   3   6   6
    27  1   0   11  12      3   2   6   7
    28  0   1   12  12      2   3   7   7
    29  1   0   12  13      3   2   7   8
    30  0   1   13  13      2   3   8   8
    31  1   0   13  14      3   2   8   9
    32  2   3   10  10      0   1   10  10
    33  3   2   10  11      1   0   10  11
    34  2   3   11  11      0   1   11  11
    35  3   2   11  12      1   0   11  12
    36  2   3   12  12      0   1   12  12
    37  3   2   12  13      1   0   12  13
    38  2   3   13  13      0   1   13  13
    39  3   2   13  14      1   0   13  14
    40  0   1   15  15      2   3   10  10
    41  1   0   15  16      3   2   10  11
    42  0   1   16  16      2   3   11  11
    43  1   0   16  17      3   2   11  12
    44  0   1   17  17      2   3   12  12
    45  1   0   17  18      3   2   12  13
    46  0   1   18  18      2   3   13  13
    47  1   0   18  19      3   2   13  14
```

Please see my code below:

```
static __device__ void function()
    {
        uint16 uBlockIdxA, uBlockIdxB, uSubBlockIdxA, usubBlockIdxB;
        if threadIdx.x < 48)
        {
            uint16 uY = threadIdx.x / 8;
            uint16 uX = threadIdx.x - (uY * 8);    
            uSubBlockIdxA = ((uY & 0x01) << 1)  + (uX & 0x01); 
            uSubBlockIdxB = ((uY & 0x01) << 1)  + ((uX + 1) & 0x01);  
            uBlockIdxB = (uY >> 1) * 5  + ((1 + uX) >> 1);
            uBlockIdxA = (uY >> 1) * 5  + ((0 + uX) >> 1);    
            func (uBlockIdxA, uBlockIdxB, uSubBlockIdxA, uSubBlockIdxB);
        }
    }
```

I am trying to think the logic to achieve what i am looking for. I am not right but not sure what i am missing.

logic as to how to generate this will be helpful. Code is appreciated. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you already know the values of your 4 subindices for every possible thread index value the kernel will read, why do you need an algorithm to calculate them? Couldn't you just put them in a look up table and directly read them? . It looks like one `char4` per thread would be all that is required

Comment: It will need to be done this way since what i have above is representation of only one cuda block. I am dealing with many such cuda blocks where the block idx changes and having lookup table will be huge. Hence look up table approach will not be a good idea and hence wanted to do it using algorithmic approach.

Comment: But the code you have shown can only ever calculate those 48 indices, no matter how many blocks or threads you run.

Comment: I appreciate your response but unfortunately got to do it this way (it is a limitation). Any help if possible will be appreciated.

Comment: Yay .... figured a way out.

Comment: If you figured it out, then please add the solution as an answer. You will be able to accept it later, which takes the question off the unanswered list and leaves the information for the next person with a similar problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code to generate the indices is below:

Split the threads into half since the indices from first half can be used for the second half with an offset of 10 and minor tweaks.

```
static __device__ void function()
{
    uint16 uBlockIdxA, uBlockIdxB, uSubBlockIdxA, usubBlockIdxB;

    if(threadIdx.x < 48)
    {
        uint16 uY = threadIdx.x / 8;
        uint16 uX = threadIdx.x - (uY * 8);

        if (threadIdx.x < 24)
        {

            uSubBlockIdxA = ((uY & 0x01) << 1)  + (uX & 0x01); 
            uSubBlockIdxB = ((uY & 0x01) << 1)  + ((uX + 1) & 0x01);  
            uBlockIdxB = (uY >> 1) * 5  + ((1 + uX) >> 1);
            uBlockIdxA = (uY >> 1) * 5  + ((0 + uX) >> 1);    

        }
        else if
        {
            uSubBlockIdxA = (((uY - 3) & 0x01) << 1)  + (uX & 0x01); 
            uSubBlockIdxB = (((uY - 3) & 0x01) << 1)  + ((uX + 1) & 0x01);  
            uBlockIdxB = ((uY - 3) >> 1) * 5  + ((1 + uX) >> 1) + 10;
            uBlockIdxA = ((uY - 3) >> 1) * 5  + ((0 + uX) >> 1) + 10;
        }
    }
    func (uBlockIdxA, uBlockIdxB, uSubBlockIdxA, uSubBlockIdxB);        
}
```