# Lookup table using Cuda-C

Tags: c, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, lookup-tables

I had figured a solution for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17334625/generate-index-using-cuda-c)  using an algorithmic approach. I was curious to try the lookup table approach suggested in one of the comments in the post as well. I am fairly new to CUDA C and tried to look for examples/information on how this can be done. I have the values stored in a table below. I know I need to associate each thread to pull each of the 4 values. The values correspond to indices SubBlkIdxA, SubBlkIdxB, BlkIdxA and BlkIdxB repectively for each thread. Once they are read from the table they are passed to a function to compute something.

I know If i say m_aIdx[3][0] it will go {3,0,0,1,}, entry in the table and read the first entry'3'. In order to read each of the entry in this location to the indices mentioned above I am thinking like this:

My table looks like this:

```
static __constant__ int16 m_aIdx[64][4] =
{
    {0,1,0,0,},
    {2,3,0,0,},
    {1,0,0,1,},
    {3,0,0,1,},
    {1,2,0,1,},
    {3,2,0,1,},
    and so on ... upto 64 entries
}
```

Function like this:

```
static __device__ void func()
{
    SubBlkIdxA = m_aIdx[3][0];
    SubBlkIdxB = m_aIdx[3][1];
    BlkIdxA = m_aIdx[3][2];
    BlkIdxB = m_aIdx[3][3];

    func1(SubBlkIdxA, SubBlkIdxB, BlkIdxA, BlkIdxB);
}
```

Speed of kernel execution is of concern to me as well. So, curious to know if this method is a good practice (efficient way to generate indices)?

Comment: It seems from the other post that you have a code for generating the indices according to a "algorithmic" approach. Above you have a draft code (it seems that you just need to address the `m_aIdx` matrix by thread/block indices) for the "non-algorithmic" approach. Why don't you compare the relative speed of the two solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Either should be pretty quick. In your “algorithmic” approach you calculate the indices based on data stored in registers, which is going to be pretty fast. In this approached you’re making a relatively well coalesced memory access to 512 Bytes of constant memory which is also pretty quick. (Even if it was poorly coalesced it will be cached pretty quickly).

What I would be concerned with is how you use these indices in func1. If statements on these indices could lead to some bad divergence, and memory accesses with these indices could lead to some poorly coalesced transfers.

One thing to consider is keeping consecutive tid’s in the same sub-blocks. Doing this will lead to cleaner memory transfers if they are on a per sub-block basis.

P.S. I’m not particularly sure how your sub blocks are structured as I’m not grasping the pattern of your indices, nor do I understand why you’re creating sub-blocks within a block instead of using smaller blocks.

Comment: Perhaps for the Kepler architecture he could use also the read-only texture cache instead of the constant memory?

Comment: Thank you all. I did compare the speeds and both methods appear to give almost the same speed numbers but nothing significantly different.

Comment: On the indices pattern, I need to differentiate boundary between subblock edges and also between block edges as I am computing a boundary strength value along those edges. That is the way the data gets processed.